# what does it mean declaring Lato:100,300,400,700

Tags: css, webfonts

what does it mean those 100,300,400 and 700 in this line

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: They're font weights

Answer (score 0):

these numbers in `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` precise which font weights you want to get.